# How can I open a different site in a new window from my page?

Tags: c#

I want to open a different website in a new window when someone visits my site.  It will be called one time per session.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'C#'? I don't see anything in this question to make it specific to C# and believe that most people will assume a javascript or php solution. Can you give more details about your specific scenario?

Answer (score 2):

onload of body call `window.open("your web url")`

```
<body onload="window.open('your web url')"/>
```

Comment: but when he click any page of web its also open again i want to open one time per session

Comment: then you want to set some bool on session variable.

Comment: Set a session variable saying whether it's the first time opening or not. Then set that in the javascript, and do a check before the window.open. Pretty simple.